# Limit of quotient of added radicals as $x\to\pm\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x^3+x}-x^4}$$

This is the last excercise for my homework, which giving me a headache for 30 minutes now. Can someone help me step by step how I can do this?

Comment: First of all, use correct MathJax formatting. Very difficult to understand the formula. Then, explain if you need two limits, one at plus, one at minus infinity.

Comment: @SkullboyBZ I have edited the question. Kindly have a look at it and modify it if you think the edit is incorrect.

Comment: you have to show that both limits are zero

Comment: @Math Lover thank you so much and yes you edit it correctly,sorry for giving you a hard time I'm still a rookie at this site :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x^3+x}-x^4}=0$$

indeed
$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac{|x|\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{|x|}\right)}{x^4\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^5}+\frac{1}{x^7}}-1\right)}=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{|x|}\right)}{|x|^3\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^5}+\frac{1}{x^7}}-1\right)}=0$$

Hope this can be useful

Comment: Thank you so much this helps a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

Write your term in the form
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}+|x|\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^4\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^5}+\frac{1}{x^8}}-1\right)}$$

Comment: My edit was to capitalize "Write" and to fix a typo ("yout" for "your").

Comment: ok thank you very much for your edit!!

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it was crucial. LOL.... I prefer to add a personal comment after an edit explaining what I did & why,

Comment: ok thank you again for your help! $n!$ times

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x^3+x}-x^4} = \frac{x^4\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x}}{x^4}\right)}{x^4\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^3+x}}{x^4}-1\right)}.$$

Comment: Omg thank you so much :D